# problem with parsecontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

hi i have a problem with the parsecontrol() method

```
Control c = this.ParseControl("<uc1:GroupListControl NickName='HARD' GroupName='STUFF' runat='server' ID='Abekat' />"); <-- error Unknown server tag 'uc1:GroupListControl'.

Control c3 = ParseControl("<asp:button id='Button3' text='Btn3' runat='server' />"); <-- this works just fine
```

why do i get the error from my own webusercontrol ? i have registered it in the html page like this

```
<%@ Register src="~/webcontrols/GroupListControl.ascx" tagname="GroupListControl" tagprefix="uc1" %>
```

Greetings Entvex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to include "Register" directive into you ParseControl statement, like the following:

```
Control c = 
                this.ParseControl("<%@ Register src=\"GroupListControl.ascx\" tagname=\"GroupListControl\" tagprefix=\"uc1\" %> <uc1:GroupListControl ID=\"GroupListControl1\" runat=\"server\" />");
```

For additional information see [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/parsecontrol_at_runtime.aspx) article.

Also maybe [Page.LoadControl method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.loadcontrol.aspx) will be useful for you.